# Which Q-value do I select as the action from the output of my Deep Q-Network?

Tags: python, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, q-learning, markov-decision-process

I'm working on a project that involves using a Deep Q-Learning Agent to learn the appropriate way to select certain nodes of a 1000-node NetworkX Graph. My `observation_space` is a (1000, 3) array, with each row representing the node label, it's degree, and a variable/attribute (either 0, 1, or 2). The `action_space` has a (1000, 1) shape, with each element corresponding to taking an action on a specified node.

This is the code for my Deep Q Network:

```
def nnmodel(observation_space, action_space):

    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, input_shape = (None, observation_space.shape[0], observation_space.shape[1]), activation='relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(action_space), activation='linear'))

    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss='mse', metrics = ['accuracy'])

    return model
```

which is, in theory and as I understand, supposed to give me the q-values from

```
q_values = model.predict(observation_space)
```

However, my `q_values` has the shape (1000, 1000) and I am unsure which "highest q-value" I should be considering that corresponds to the node that the agent should perform an action on. Is it the highest q-value entry, for which the row / column corresponds to the node the agent should be selecting? Or is it the largest row/column sum? Or is it something else entirely? Examples I've looked at online typically use `np.argmax(q_values[0])`, which I feel does not apply to my case.

Also, does my `input_shape` look correct for the problem I'm describing?

Any help is appreciated!

```
max_q = np.max(q_values)
position = np.where(q_values == max_q)
print(position)
```

This returns the index of the largest q-value. I'm unsure if this means I should be selecting the i-th/j-th node for the ith row or j-th column.

Comment: Your network gives 1000 outputs for each row in your observations_space. I think it should five 1 output for each row in your observations_space?

Comment: Shouldn't the output be the size of the action space? Meaning that if there are 1000 possible actions, the output layer should have 1000 outputs?

Comment: So, you have 1000 nodes with 3 states for each and 1 action for each node making it 1000 actions. Am I right?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.